# How to Style iOS Navigation Bar in Dropbox Connection Screen

Tags: ios, dropbox, uiappearance

I want to be able to specify the background color of the navigation bar I see when my app opens the Dropbox SDK's modal. As far as I can tell, I can't obtain a reference to that controller.

This is how I call it when using the Datastore API:

```
DBAccountManager.sharedManager().linkFromController(self)
```

...and this is how I call it with SwiftyDropbox (v2 API):

```
Dropbox.authorizeFromController(self)
```

Is there a way to reference that navigation controller so that I can style it?

[image: Datastore Connection Screen]
[image: Version 2 API Connection Screen]

Comment: The SDK doesn't offer an official way to get or control this, but we'll consider this a feature request.

Comment: Is there a class name I can use so I can try and target it with `appearanceWhenContainedIn(Class)`?